# ag: Search all folders except for folderName/subFolder (Perl Regex)

Tags: regex, perl, ag

I have these folders that have subfolders in them...

```
locales/US/en
locales/US/fr
locales/FR/en
locales/FR/fr
locales/DE/en
locales/DE/fr
public
test
[...]
```

I want Silver Searcher to ignore `locales/*` EXCEPT for `locales/US/en/*` (essentially I only care about `US/en` locale files)

This works, EXCEPT that it doesn't show the other folders in root (public and test):
`ag -l -G '(locales)/(US)'`

I believe AG uses Perl Regexes. Any thoughts?

Comment: Isn't this really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037307/expand-command-line-exclude-pattern-with-zsh/37056810#37056810

Answer (score 0):

If it is perl regular expressions this should give you the expected result:

```
^(?:locales/US/en|(?!locales))
```

Explanation:

```
^   = anchor regular expression to start of string.
(?: = group which is not captured
|   = Alternation for alternative capture
(?! = negative look ahead assertion - ensures that the string isnt starting with locales, unless it is starting with locales/US/en
```